# How do I track mobile app and website traffic?

Tags: google-analytics

According to [this post](http://analytics.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/understanding-multi-device-user.html), I can now track web and app traffic through one property.

> Now you can see all data you send to one Google Analytics property in a single reporting view, regardless of the collection method you use of where the data comes from. If you send data from the web and from a mobile app to one property, both data sets appear in your reports.

However, when I create either a new account, property, or view, I'm always asked 'What would you like to track?', and given the option to select either 'Website' or 'Mobile App'. How do I create say a property that allows me to track both? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks,

Craig

Answer (score 0):

That choice is a bit misleading, and I think possibly left over from a previous product cycle (it used to change what metric names you saw appear in the reporting interface, but now there's only one set of names). As of now, I think it only changes the icon that appears in the account/property/view screen.

So, you should be able to choose either option, tag both properties with same UA ID, and get the desired results.